# List Type Conversion Error

Tags: c#, list, type-conversion

I have two files that I am editing to check from sets of lists. I am getting the following error on one line of one of the files: "Cannot implicitly convert List(string) to List(G.E.RE.DC)" I can't seem to figure out how to fix the error. Nothing else is showing up as having a problem.

Here is the first set of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace G.E.RE
{
    [Metadata("Claim", MetadataType.Object)]

    public class Claim
    {
        private List<string> diagCodes = new List<string>();
    }
    public List<DiagnosisCode> DC
    {
        get
        {
            if (testData != null)
                return testData.DC; //This is the line that shows the error

            return this.DC;
        }
        set
        {
            this.DC = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second set of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using G.E.D.E.RE;

namespace G.E.RE
{
    public List<string> DC { get; set; }

    public class DC
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int ICDVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to return a `List<string>` when it's a property defined as a `List<DiagnosisCode>`?

Comment: In the first snippet, is `DC` supposed to be a property of `Claim`?  I assume it is.  But in the second snippet, I can't tell to which class `public List<string> DC { get; set; }` belongs.  Is it some interface?

Comment: @ConradFrix, once you said that I went back and realized that it was a stupid mistake on my part. I didn't even think about the property being defined. Guess all you need sometimes is for someone else to take a look at your code. Thanks. Error's gone now. :P

Comment: where is `testData` declared?

Comment: @Jason9024 if you fixed it then either delete the question, or post the answer so it is not left hanging.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Conrad pointed out that my property is defined as List so I changed other List to the same type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using G.E.D.E.RE;

namespace G.E.RE
{
    public List<DiagnosisCode> DC { get; set; }

    public class DC
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int ICDVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```